# How can we make a list editable?

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I want to make my `JList` editable, what should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a 1-column `JTable` instead.

Answer (score 3):

[List Editor](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/19/list-editor/)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the source code for an editable list here:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/EditableListExample.htm

Depending on your use case an `JComboBox`, which is editable, might be a better solution than a `JList`.

Comment: This is not an editable list, but an example how to use 1-column JTable.